# Password entropy boosting

Tags: passwords, entropy

Can the process of generating a password based on the transformation of random 3D data into a 2D data chain have better entropy than other methods of generating 2D random data chains?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about information security. You essentially ask how to convert some imaginary 3D QR code into another (2D) visual form. For this question it does not matter if you want to use the other form to generate passwords or something else, i.e. the transformation you ask about is not specific to information security.

Comment: This type of transformation, any 3D object to signs/characters, would be seen as another technique (perhaps a policy) to create passwords. The passwords are about the security of information, as I understand it. So maybe me (or anyone) can just reformulate the problem?

Comment: What you say is quite unclear to me. You want to create passwords from 3d qr code, I see no point in doing so. The best passwords are made from random data. So for example, 5 random english words. You don't need 3d qr code to do that.

Comment: Not necessarily QR. It could be anything, also ~random event like water drops states closed and frozen in 3D space.

Comment: @merlenoir: You are only asking to transform a 3D data representation of data into a 2D representation. This is not an information security problem. It does not magically get such a problem by adding that you then want to create passwords from this 2D representation because this is actually the step after you solved your non-security problem.

Comment: Steffen, combinatorics or the concept of entropy do not directly concern information security. And I know your future answer, but I will wait for someone else sharing your point of view.

Comment: @merlenoir Any type of transformation, any object to any object, can be seen as another technique to create passwords. But it doesn't mean question about transforming html to pdf is in scope of this site. Your question is about 3D modeling file formats as I can see it, voting to close.

Comment: But what's the point of 3D?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you perhaps explain what concrete problem you are having? And perhaps define "3D data" and "2D data".

Comment: @Anders: I am trying to transform a natural born random event (its form of occurrence in natural conditions) or digitally generated pseudo random event (simulation), anyways, a raw image into chain of random symbols somehow generated from the event's way of occurrence keeping its form (the image). In other words I want to fold/transform/convert three-dimensional randomness into two-dimensional randomness. And I am also trying to determine whether is it possible and reasonable (given the entropy of the process) or not. It seems to be closer to not.

Comment: Seriously though, what is this question even asking? What is "3D data"? How is that any different from "2D data"? As far as computers are concerned data is just a sequence of bits; there's nothing about it that is inherently 3D or 2D.

Comment: Perhaps _data_ is not the best _notion_ I can use. I meant _data_ in more general and abstract sense. Of course I am aware there is nothing more than electrical signals at the end. Ok, I am also voting to close. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing one of two things:

1. A process in which data is generated *somewhat* randomly, but constrained by being mapped to a 3D structure with certain properties. If so, it will necessarily be less random than a method that is not constrained in that way.
2. A process in which completely random data happens to be projected into 3 dimensions. If so, the initial projection is immaterial to the underlying entropy of the data ... but any subsequent transformation (converting to raw 2D equivalents, using base64, etc.) could do nothing to improve the entropy. And that transformation might make it worse if it has non-random components.

Either way, the process you're describing would be no better than random data - and could be worse.